# Short-hand boolean logic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean-logic, conditional-operator, shorthand

I'm beginner on JavaScript and AngularJS. So I encounter following code from Adam Freeman books

```
var selectedCategory = null;
...
$scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {
   return selectedCategory == null || 
      product.category === selectedCategory;
};
```

I get confused by the `return` statement above, can you guys **re-write** the code above with clear code (no shorthand).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short-hand form of returning a `boolean` value. Look closely:

```
 return selectedCategory == null || product.category === selectedCategory;
```

Here, `return` statement has two expressions:

1. `selectedCategory == null`
2. `product.category === selectedCategory`

When the method returns, it will evaluate these two expressions separately. Consider yout `selectedCategory` is `null`, and the `product.category` is equal to `selectedCategory` then the statement is

```
return true || true;
```

which will eventually simplifies to

```
return true; // (true || true) = true
```

Likewise, you can think of this expressions return value by substituting values and evaluate them separately.

Longer version for this is:

```
if (selectedCategory == null || product.category == selectedCategory) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the `else` block in your long version.

Comment: @BenM Yes. I know. Just put it there to be more clear for the OP as he's a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement could be re-written easily as an `if()` block as follows:

```
$scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {

   if( selectedCategory == null || product.category === selectedCategory )
   {
       return true;
   }

   return false;
};
```

Essentially, the `return` is going to return `true` if *either* of the specified conditions is `true`. Otherwise, it will return `false`.